# php how to save the day , month and year enter by user in variables to show value in database

Tags: php, database, wordpress

User enter the date , month and year and then press a button to show him the value of database based on the day he picked but I do not know how to save the day , month and year in $d , $m and $y variables

```
<style>
.button {border-radius: 8px;} 
.button1 {font-size: 20px;}
</style>
<form>

اليوم : <input id="txtDay" type="text" placeholder="DD" />

الشهر : <input id="txtMonth" type="text" placeholder="MM" />

السنة : <input id="txtYear" type="text" placeholder="YYYY" />

<button id="but" onclick="daily()">إظهار الإستهلاك اليومي</button>

</form>

<script>// <![CDATA[
// to show the right value from database
  function daily() {

  $current_user=get_current_user_id();// to fetch the right data for the right user

  // takes the values ​​entered by the user
global $wpdb;
$d=???????????//define variable to store the day enter by user 
$m=???????????//define variable to store the month enter by user 
$y=???????????//define variable to store the year enter by user 
$daily_amount= $wpdb->get_var("SELECT daily_amount FROM arduino_period_use where ID=$current_user and day=$d and month=$m and year=$y ");
print_r($daily_amount); 
}
// ]]></script
```

Comment: You are using PHP in a javascript fragment. Maybe a few hours with a book would be your best bet

Answer (score -1):

Add a name to

`<input id="txtDay" type="text" placeholder="DD" />`

for example:

`<input name="txtDay" id="txtDay" type="text" placeholder="DD" />`

then you can use it as `$_POST['txtDay']` or, when you want to use it as `$d` you can write `$d = $_POST['txtDay']`.

All in case you send your form data with POST! And I hope that your posted PHP code is on server side.

Comment: thanks but Is there a problem in the onclick function for the button because when i click on the button do not show the result